# 2D Vector not properly saved and loaded with boost::serialize library

Tags: c++, serialization, vector, boost

I have a `vector<vector<char>>` object, that I want to save and load from a file:

```
class Bar {
  private:
    std::vector<std::vector<char>> _map;

    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template <class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version) {
        for(int i=0; i<_map.size(); ++i){
            // ar & _map[i];
        }
        ar & _map;
    }
};
```

While the for loop works, the direct approach with `ar & _map;` saves and load the map with wrong dimensions and values.

I tried to test it with the example code from boost:

```
// create and modify example object of class Bar here...
Bar s();
std::ofstream ofs("map_save.save");
{
    boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
    oa << s;
}

Bar news();
{
    std::ifstream ifs("map_save.save");
    boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);
    ia >> news;
}
```

This is how the different 2D vectors look like. (The right one is the one on top:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 C 0 0 0 0 
0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
------------
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 C 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 
1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 
1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 
1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Why did you omit the relevant code and post code that can't compile?

Comment: I thought my mistake was in the way I used the boost serialization. Sorry for the bad example, I try to update my question as soon as possible!

Answer (score 2):

You are doing something else wrong that you're not showing:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/655f65eae48ff226)</kbd>**

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>

using namespace std;

class Bar {
  public:
    void seed(std::vector<std::vector<char>> const& init) { _map = init; }
    bool operator==(Bar const& other) const {
        return _map == other._map;
    }
  private:
    std::vector<std::vector<char>> _map;

    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template <class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int /*version*/) {
        //for(size_t i=0; i<_map.size(); ++i){ ar & _map[i]; }
        ar & _map;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<char>> seed = {
        {'0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'},
        {'0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'C', '0', '0', '0', '0'},
        {'0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'},
        {'0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'},
        {'0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'},
        {'0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'},
        {'0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'},
        {'0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'},
        {'0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'},
        {'0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'},
    };

    // create and modify example object of class Bar here...
    {
        Bar s;
        s.seed(seed);
        std::ofstream ofs("map_save.save");
        boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
        oa << s;
    }

    {
        Bar news;
        std::ifstream ifs("map_save.save");
        boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);
        ia >> news;


        Bar compareTo;
        compareTo.seed(seed);
        std::cout << "Comparison: " << std::boolalpha << (compareTo == news) << "\n";
    }
}*
```

Prints:

```
Comparison: true
```